# Laptop crashes after being on for about 10sec - 1min

Tags: crash

The laptop, a Acer  travelmate 5740g(its about 6years old) keeps on crashing after being on for about +/-20 seconds i've taken out the harddrive to see if its that and it still does the same. Also did that to the Ram but it still crashes anyone have an idea on what it might be? and on how to fix it?

Comment: If you can provide mini dump file that may be helpful. If you once had overheating problems and that damaged the internal circuitry components, then you may have damage to the motherboard for example so you may need to take it apart and give the internal components a visual inspection for obvious damage (e.g. swollen capacitors, ooze, sooty dust, burn marks, heat check discoloration, etc.). Consider taking a can of compressed air with all electrical power off, and blowing dust out of the enclosure as well in case it's restricting air flow needed to keep it cool.

Comment: I'll see what i can do

Answer (score 0):

It might be a temperature problem, your CPU reaches a maximum temperature and shuts down to prevent damage. Is it possible that the thermal paste holding the heatsink to the CPU has deteriorated? Have you tried dusting the laptop and ensuring that all the fans are working correctly?

Comment: I have but new thermal paste on it and it still does the same. It did crash before on overheating, and the fan did run almost always on full before it started crashing. But after i cleaned it it was better. but still crashes.

Comment: Huh, that is odd. When you say crash, is there any information provided about the crash? For example, does the OS hang / freeze, or does the screen just cut to black and the system shuts down?

Comment: it just cuts of completely plug in or running on battery.